# Knockout: Adding items into map of hierarchical json

Tags: json, knockout.js

I'm trying Knockout mapping, and would like to know if it is possible to insert an item into the sub-levels of a hierarchical json model.

Using a Json something like this, can I then add an item into sub-level?  Add an apple?

```
var food = [ 
{foodGroupName: "Fruits", subGroups: [
    {subGroupName: "Apples", values: [    
        {"mytitle":"Granny Apple","mycaption":"Muffin sweet roll marshmallow."},
        {"mytitle":"Green Apple","mycaption":"Jelly beans sugar plum lemon drops."},
        {"mytitle":"Crab Apple","mycaption":"Sesame snaps gingerbread pudding cupcake."}
    ]},
    {subGroupName: "Oranges", values: [   
        {"mytitle":"Navel Orange","mycaption":"Muffin sweet roll marshmallow."},
        {"mytitle":"Blood Orange","mycaption":"Jelly beans sugar plum lemon drops."},
        {"mytitle":"Mandarin Orange","mycaption":"Sesame snaps gingerbread pudding cupcake."},
        {"mytitle":"Clementine","mycaption":"Pudding jelly-o dessert soufflé."}
    ]}
]
},
{foodGroupName: "Vegetables", subGroups: []},
{foodGroupName: "Proteins", subGroups: []}
```

];

I put together a Fiddle:  **http://jsfiddle.net/e7bmt74b/5/**

I would like to make the "Add New" button add a new type of apple, and have it be added to the Json as shown in textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should seriously consider restructuring your data. Right now it's not easy to insert an apple because you need to get the first item of the array (which happens to be the fruit section) and then insert into the proper subgroup (which happens to be the first subgroup).

```
this.addApple = function() {
    self.foods()[0].subGroups()[0].values.push({
        mytitle: ko.observable('New Apple Title'),
        mycaption: ko.observable('New Apple Caption'),
    });
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7bmt74b/7/)

I noticed you're using the mapping plugin. While good for some cases I would recommend against using it at first. It actually makes things like this much harder. Take the time and build up a some good domain models. Ideally you'd have something more like this.

```
this.addApple = function () {
    self.fruits().apples.push(new Apple());
};
```

Or even better, let a"fruits" object handle it.

```
this.addApple = function () {
    self.fruits.addApple();
};
```

tl;dr: It's not trivial because your data structure is complicated.

Comment: I can still restructure the data.  I used the mapping plugin because I did not know how to display hierarchical data without it.  I've been working on it for a week now, just trying to get a hierarchical Json model to be displayed and editable.  I suspect your recommendations are correct, but I don't know how to get there.